# Можно ли как то собирать 2 файла в Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "Server/server.ts"
    ]
}
```

Это конфиг, мне сейчас нужно собрать клиент но в отдельный файл

Answer (score 1):

В общем решение оказалось простым в папке Client я положил файлик

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "../client.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "../Server/server.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

И в папке Server тоже положил файлик

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "../server.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "server.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
"files": [
    "Server/server.ts", 
    "Server/file2.ts" 
]
```

Посмотрите [typescript-watcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-watcher) или [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) или [grunt-typedcript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-typescript)

С помошью них по желанию можно настроить автоматическую сборку и в отдельную папку.